# How to replace dynatree node with new node?

Tags: jquery, json, contextmenu, dynatree

I have created a dynatree with right contex menu which further has a sub-menu. The requirement is such that on click of any of the item of the sub-menu, the sub-menu item should replace the tree node from which is activated. Followin is the pictorial view:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI-> Lets say on right click of GHI, we have a context menu->XYZ which further has a sub-menu-> PQR. Now what I want is that on click of PQR, it should replace GHI.
```

I have the following code written to create the tree and context menus.

```
$(function(){
        $("#tree").dynatree({

            initAjax: {
                url: "sample-data1.json"
                }  ,
            onActivate: function(node) {
                $("#echoActive").text(node.data.title);

            },
            onDeactivate: function(node) {
                $("#echoActive").text("-");
            }


        });
    }); 

function ReplaceTest() {
                var tree = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree");


                }


     function Replace()
            {
                var f = function(){ReplaceTest();};
                setTimeout(f,0);

            }

 <div>
    <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Employee Data</a>
            <ul>         
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Replace()">Name</a></li>         
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Replace()">Desig</a></li>           
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Replace()">ID</a></li>          
  <li><a href="#" onclick="Replace()">Mob</a></li>        
  </ul> 
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the above code I've given onclick() method on sub-menu items, but not able to go ahead with this. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rename the current node, you can use

```
var node = $("#tree").dynatree("getActiveNode");
node.data.title = "My new title";
node.render();
```

Comment: How can I apply this to the tooltip?